# User authentication, management

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have recently started studying JavaScript, nodeJS, and reactJS on the front-end, and I have some questions about best practices to apply in this JavaScript world. I would like to ask for opinions regarding how I could improve my code.

Starting with an example: I have 2 functions, with different ways of handling promises

Here I have a route to add a user:

```
 addUsers(req,res,next) {
    try {
        const {name,email,login} = req.body;
        User.existLogin(req.body.login)
        .then(async result => {
            if(!result){
                const password = await bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
                User.create({ 
                    name, email, login, password }).then(result => {
                    res.status(201).json({Results: result.dataValues})
                })
            }else{
                return res.status(409).json({message: 'Login already exists'}); 
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error})
    }
}
```

And here I have another function to login:

```
async login(req,res){
    const  user  = await User.existLogin(req.body.login);
    if (!user) { return res.status(400).json({result: 'Login is wrong '});} 
    const isPassword = await User.isPassword(user.dataValues.password, req.body.password);
    if (!isPassword) { return res.status(400).json({result: 'Password is wrong '}); } 
    const jwt = auth.signjwt(auth.payload(user));
    console.log(jwt);
    res.status(200);
    res.json(jwt);
}
```

Looking at this the login function seems to me to be cleaner, but I have doubts if really yours I could improve in one of two (I follow different logics to do both).

I have an auth folder, where I export functions, such as my payload, my sign, my middlware to validate my jwt, but I don't know if this is a correct decision.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User')
const config= require('../config/dbconfig');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    signjwt (payload) {
        return jwt.sign(payload, 
            config.secretToken
                   )
    },
    payload (usuario) {
        return {
            sub: usuario.id,
            name: usuario.nome,
            email: usuario.email,
            login: usuario.username,
            admin: true,
            iat: Math.floor(moment.now()/1000), // Timestamp de hoje
            exp: moment().add(10, 'minutes').unix() // Validade de 2 dias
        }
    },
    async auth(req,res,next){
        const token = req.header('Authorization');
        console.log(token);
        if(!token) return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized');
        try{
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token,config.secretToken);
            const user = await User.findByPk(decoded.sub);
            console.log(user);
            if(!user){
                return res.status(404).json('User not Found');
            }
            res.json(user);
            next();
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            res.status(400).json('Invalid Token');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `try {} catch {}` doesn't make sense in the first function as you need to use `.catch()` of the Promise itself (also, your function doesn't return anything because the `return` is inside a Promise). Conversely, the second function needs `try {} catch {}` because that's how async/await workflow is handled. As for "best practices" there's quite a few things to improve here depending on whose "best practices" you want to follow, but there's one universal thing: use ESLint with a popular set of rules which you like and read the usual "best practices" compilations.

Comment: thansk bro u can post awnser for give vote positive ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Initial thoughts:

This code looks very ... compressed without strictly needing to. Another thing that I notice is the level of nesting that shows in here.

Generally speaking it doesn't particularly make a difference how you decide to handle Promises, in the vast majority of cases it's just a matter of personal preference.

One thing you do *not* need to worry about is specially handling a promise rejection, since express automatically converts thrown errors into an appropriate response. That is what `login` takes advantage of to look so clean.

One final initial thing I notice is the inconsistency that shows in the code.

#### Inconsistencies:

Compare the use of spaces in the following example:

```
const  user   = await User.existLogin(req.body.login);
const isPassword = await User.isPassword(user.dataValues.password, req.body.password);
```

Or compare the use of braces as well as whitespace for these examples:

```
if(!token) return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized');
if (!user) { return res.status(400).json({result: 'Login is wrong '});}
if(!user){
    return res.status(404).json('User not Found');
}
```

Compare also the use of newlines and indentation levels in the following examples:

```
User.create({
    name, email, login, password }).then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({Results: result.dataValues})
})
return jwt.sign(payload,
    config.secretToken
           )
return {
    sub: usuario.id,
    // ....
    exp: moment().add(10, 'minutes').unix()
}
```

All this is to say: **Pick one style and stick to it**. Whichever style you decide on, it makes it easier to read if the style is ***consistent***.

Personally I prefer a style with more space than you've shown here for most cases.

#### Indentation:

You're using a strange mix of indentation styles and you're making lots of use of early returns, except in some small cases where I don't understand it. I personally prefer to almost always return early inside the request handler and if there's more complex logic I'd consider extracting that into a separate function. That yields code which will look a lot like this:

```
function addUsers(req, res) {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const login = req.body.login;

    const exists = await User.existLogin(login);
    if (exists) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Login already exists' });
    }

    const password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    const created = User.create({ name, email, login, password });
    res.status(201).json({ results: created.dataValue });
}
```

Note that I removed the use of `await` with `hashSync` (should be clear why).
Also note that I lower-cased the member `results` in the returned JSON result.

Obviously this doesn't quite have the same error behaviour as the code presented in the question, but it nicely shows how to avoid deeply nesting blocks.

#### HTTP / web standard authorization patterns

As a minor point I'd like to add that the `auth` middleware shown here is not quite following the common header authorization pattern. It's missing a response header indicating the expected authorization type. Since you're working with a token here, usually the header would be `'WWW-Authenticate: "Bearer"'`, but that would imply the expected `Authorization` header should start with `"Bearer"`, which is not the case here.

To be more ... standard-conform I'd expect a proper bearer-token Authentication scheme to specifically define the authorization *type* used in the scheme. An option could be to explicitly specify you expect a jwt-token as type resulting in the following headers:

```
'WWW-Authenticate: "jwt-token"'
---
'Authorization: "jwt-token <jwt_token_goes_here>"'
```

Note that this suggestion of course would require an adjustment to the way the token is obtained, adding another way the request can be malformed :)

#### Conclusion:

All in all this is a solid start, to get this code to the next level just requires a few tweaks, mostly around being consistent in how the code is structured in itself.

Well done :)